# Nginx downloads HTML file after rewrite from PHP file

Tags: php, nginx

I am using the following rewrite in sites-available/default

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/[^.]+/[^.]+/([^-]*).html$ /release.php?id=$1 break;
}
```

`domain.com/release.php?id=abc123` works correctly

`domain.com/the-artist/title-title/123456.html` tries to download an HTML file called `123456.html` (and includes the correct source code)

How can I display the HTML instead of downloading?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure nginx to serve HTML files for viewing instead of downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572533/how-to-configure-nginx-to-serve-html-files-for-viewing-instead-of-downloading)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `last` other than `break`

> last
>   stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives and starts a search for a new location matching the changed URI;
>
> break
>   stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives as with the break directive;